# Microsoft Flow connection issue with Yammer

Tags: yammer, power-automate

Is Microsoft Flow a first party app or third-party app? I am asking this because I am unable to authenticate from Flow --> Yammer where 3rd party application is OFF at Yammer network.

Comment: If you are not Microsoft or working for Microsoft, Microsoft is third party.

Comment: My understanding is Microsoft Flow is first party app for yammer but like to check other's opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow was moved under the first party umbrella about 3 months ago.  It should no longer require 3rd party apps to be enabled in your network to use.

There are apparently different versions of the Flow app in Yammer and moving them all into first party status is in the works.  In the meantime, the Flow app listed in the Yammer App Directory should work without third party apps enabled.  There's a chance Flow itself will intervene and send you to a different version of the app.  If that's the case, 3rd party apps will have to be enabled to use it until all versions of the Flow app are considered first party.